# How do I make a Vue component occupy the entire browser height?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm learning Vue 3 and I'm trying to make a simple sidebar for an app I'm trying to build

I have two divs: `main` and `sidebar`, and I have given both of them (and the body) `height: 100%`

However, the divs are not occupying the full height of the window.

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    hi
  </div>
</template>

<style>
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

This is how the site looks at the moment.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnMSe.png)

Comment: Hi, Use `height: 100vh`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100%`.
`vh` itself means `Viewport Height`, if we use `10vh` as the value, it will occupy 10% of the current viewport height. Since sidebar and main class is inside the body, the height will refer to the parent class, which is body. Hence, occupying 100% of the body class, which is 100vh.

```
<template>
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    hi
  </div>
</template>

<style>
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: vh isn't handled properly on iOS

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of 100vh on iOS? It works perfectly on me

Answer (score 0):

For height in `%` to work, all parent elements much have a height set. In your case `<body>` has a `%` height of `100%` but it's parent, HTML doesn't have a height set.

So your code should be

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

<sup>*</sup> `<html>` is an exception to this since it is the root and doesn't have a parent.

---

Another option is to use `vh` unit as mentioned in comments which is relative to the height of [view port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts) instead of parent, unlike the `%` unit.